# Include Excel Value in Stored Procedure SQL

Tags: sql, excel

I have a stored procedure that I run through Excel (I have SQL Anywhere ODBC set up) and I need it to look at the value in Cell A1, which will change daily.

A1 will hold the value =Today()

My stored procedure SQL currently is:

sp_late_billing_mco '2011-10-15'

I want this statement to refer to Cell A1 rather than typing the date every time I go to run it.  I've tried different things and I get error messages.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please show us your code attempts, so that we can advise on amendments?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to provide the value from A1 to the stored procedure as a parameter instead of having SQL Server "read" the value from your spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you change your query and do:

```
DECLARE @Date DATETIME
SELECT @Date = GETDATE()

EXEC sp_late_billing_mco @Date
```

Or you can change your stored procedure so it doesn't recieve a parameter and put the first two lines of the query above in it.

Answer (score 0):

Use VBA to get the value from the cell.

```
DIM MyDate as date
DIM Datestr as string
MyDate = Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(1,1).Value
DateStr = Year(MyDate)&"-"&Month(MyDate)&"-"&Day(MyDate)
```

Now insert DateStr into the query text and rerun the query.